# {f(x) belongs to R[x] | f(n) belongs to Z for all n belongs to Z}uncountable or countable ? (TIFR GS 2022)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\{f\in \mathbb{R}[x] | \forall n\in \mathbb{Z},\;f(n)\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is uncountable or countable?
Here I thought that if we take any combination of $x^i$ for all $i$ then it become like power set of natural number ...Is it ok to say that it is uncountable?

Comment: It's not okay to say that it is uncountable since you account only for finite combinations of $x^i$s under the assumption that $f\in \mathbb{R}[X]$. The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: @RichoddAsscraft can you give the solution??Is it uncountable ar countable???

Answer (score 3):

The set of polynomials with real (or complex) coefficients which map integers to integers is larger than $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, but not much larger. It is the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of the rational polynomials $\binom{X}{m}$ for $m=0,1,2,\ldots$. Here the “binomial polynomial” $\binom{X}{m}$ is simply

$$\binom{X}{m} = \frac{X(X-1)\cdots(X-m+1)}{m!}$$

Since every such polynomial is a **finite** linear combination of these basic polynomials, and the coefficients belong to a countable set, the set of such polynomials is itself countable.